What is this 4-pin fan header?
What is the name of this 4-pin fan header, in the first image?  This is from an Intel NUC motherboard, and there is 1.0mm between each pin.  Will I be able to get and use an adapter for the much more common 3-/4-pin fan connectors, such as the 3-pin piece shown in the second image?



From this page about the NUC12, there is an image (image G):

This image has an associated table:



Pin Number
Pin Definition - Signal




1
Ground


2
Tachometer


3
+12V


4
Pulse-Width Modulation (PWM)



I don't know much about fans but this also matches the descriptions given in some of the posts here.
I don't know if this header has a specific name but I do know you can buy fans specifically for Intel NUCs (for example), in which case you don't really have to think about it or mess with adapters.


What is the name of this 4-pin fan header, in the first image?

It looks like a cross to a 3-wall Molex Picoblade header from a different manufacturer.

1.0mm between each pin

If you really mean "between", then the pitch is more than 1 mm. Likely 1.25 mm.

Apologies.  I believe it's 1mm between the centers of each pin.

"I believe it's 1mm between the centers of each pin. ", Well, I don't believe it. Because I don't believe that there is a 1 mm pitch connector that looks like your connector. Your connector looks like a Molex PicoBlade and its pitch is 1.25 mm.

No it won't, that connector isn't keyed the right way. My suggestion would be to find out what the connector is and cut the connector off of the fan cable and install a new one. In addition most of the standard connectors are 0.1".
If the pitch and conductor order is the same you might be able to shave down the connector and force it in but it's not worth it just get a new fan

In order to install a new connector (or to get a new fan that already has the right connector), what's the name of the connector that I need to get, which will match this header?

Not sure, look and see if they have a BOM in their documentation. Also you could provide pitch and a schematic that would be useful

The ACES logo (in the manual, see this answer) is a good hint.  Their online catalog isn't the easiest to navigate, but some poking around turns up a likely candidate:

ACES 51241
With 1.25mm pitch and ~0.3mm thick terminals, the measurement of ~1mm between pins seems close enough to the eye.

It's that a knock-off of a Molex Picoblade?

It sure looks like it. At least two ACES parts that I know of are clones/compatible with brand-name series, though I don't know if anyone has a direct cross table?

Fans can either be two-pin (power only)
3-pin (power, speed control)
4-pin (power, speed control, speed feedback)
Adapters are available to connect a fan with less pins to a mobo whose headers have more pins

I've also seen 3-out-of-4: no speed control (or that manual on the fan body or a bracket), but speed feedback.  That was a while ago, maybe not still sold.

@ChrisH At least in the realm of PC fans, that's actually standard. On a standard PC fan header, pins 1 and 2 are ground and power, pin 3 is tach, and pin 4 is PWM. A 3-pin fan uses its third pin for tach, and controls speed by varying the voltage supplied. A 4-pin fan supplies a constant voltage and sends a PWM signal on the 4th pin to control speed. I don't think I've ever heard of a 3-pin fan where the third pin is any form of 'speed control'.
